# Sonar 3.7.2 -Support for SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sonarqube

We have SONAR installed in a LINUX world using the native driver to connect to SQL, and are having no issues per se, but we are currently using SQL 2012 as our backend DB and wonder if SONAR fully supports SQL 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean SQL Server 2012, right? If so, it is not supported and we have no plan to support it.